# How to initialize toasts with JavaScript in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, toast, bootstrap-5

I can't initialize Bootstrap 5 Toasts.

The button to initialize the toast:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="toastbtn">Initialize toast</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("toastbtn").onclick = function() {
        var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
        var toastList = toastElList.map(function(toastEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl, option)
        })
      };
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5e1t3scp/

And [here's the documentation](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/#usage).

The JavaScript has been taken from Bootstrap's website. I tried many times but couldn't initialize it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since the second parameter of the constructor is optional, it is unnecessary. However, if you would like to supply options, you should do so in the form of an object:

```js
// Defaults according to the documentation
{
  animation: true,
  autohide: true,
  delay: 500
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container mt-5">

      <!-- button to initialize toast -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="toastbtn">Initialize toast</button>

      <!-- Toast -->
      <div class="toast">
        <div class="toast-header">
          <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
          <small>11 mins ago</small>
          <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
          Hello, world! This is a toast message.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Popper.js first, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("toastbtn").onclick = function() {
        var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
        var toastList = toastElList.map(function(toastEl) {
        // Creates an array of toasts (it only initializes them)
          return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl) // No need for options; use the default options
        });
       toastList.forEach(toast => toast.show()); // This show them
   
        console.log(toastList); // Testing to see if it works
      };

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I still don't see it. Am I not supposed to see a toast notification when I click on the button? Like the ones on Bootstrap's documentation page?

Comment: Whoops! Looks like you have to call '.show()' on the toasts to reveal them! (I fixed my answer).

Comment: That's work fine but show all tost, if I have more of toast with different id and I was to visualize only one of them?

Comment: Now, you can do like this: Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
        .forEach(toastNode => new bootstrap.Toast(toastNode).show());

Answer (score 12):

If you would to show only the part with a definited id this is the code

```
document.getElementById("toastbtn").onclick = function() {
    var myAlert =document.getElementById('toastNotice');//select id of toast
    var bsAlert = new bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);//inizialize it
    bsAlert.show();//show it
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container mt-5">

      <!-- button to initialize toast -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="toastbtn">Initialize toast</button>

      <!-- Toast -->
      <div id="toastNotice" class="toast">
        <div class="toast-header">
          <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
          <small>11 mins ago</small>
          <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body">
          Hello, world! This is a toast message.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Popper.js first, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("toastbtn").onclick = function() {
        var myAlert =document.getElementById('toastNotice');//select id of toast
          var bsAlert = new bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);//inizialize it
          bsAlert.show();//show it
      };

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

I (full disclosure) made package that essentially makes it extremely easy for you to call snacks, toasts, and modals from JS and the repo can be found [here](https://github.com/Script47/bs5-utils/).

**Code**

```js
const bs5Utils = new Bs5Utils();

bs5Utils.Snack.show('secondary', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('light', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('white', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('dark', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('info', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('primary', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('success', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('warning', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('danger', 'Hello World!', 0, true);

bs5Utils.Toast.show({
    type: 'primary',
    icon: `<i class="far fa-check-circle fa-lg me-2"></i>`,
    title: 'Notification!',
    subtitle: '23 secs ago',
    content: 'Hello World!',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Click Me!',
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
            handler: () => {
                alert(`Button #1 has been clicked!`);
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Click Me Too!',
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
            handler: () => {
                alert(`You clicked me too!`);
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'dismiss',
            text: 'Hide',
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary'
        }
    ],
    delay: 0,
    dismissible: true
});
```

[image]

**Live Example**

```js
"use strict";function _classPrivateMethodInitSpec(t,e){_checkPrivateRedeclaration(t,e),e.add(t)}function _defineProperty(t,e,s){return e in t?Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:s,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):t[e]=s,t}function _classPrivateMethodGet(t,e,s){if(!e.has(t))throw new TypeError("attempted to get private field on non-instance");return s}function _classPrivateFieldInitSpec(t,e,s){_checkPrivateRedeclaration(t,e),e.set(t,s)}function _checkPrivateRedeclaration(t,e){if(e.has(t))throw new TypeError("Cannot initialize the same private elements twice on an object")}function _classPrivateFieldSet(t,e,s){return _classApplyDescriptorSet(t,_classExtractFieldDescriptor(t,e,"set"),s),s}function _classApplyDescriptorSet(t,e,s){if(e.set)e.set.call(t,s);else{if(!e.writable)throw new TypeError("attempted to set read only private field");e.value=s}}function _classPrivateFieldGet(t,e){return _classApplyDescriptorGet(t,_classExtractFieldDescriptor(t,e,"get"))}function _classExtractFieldDescriptor(t,e,s){if(!e.has(t))throw new TypeError("attempted to "+s+" private field on non-instance");return e.get(t)}function _classApplyDescriptorGet(t,e){return e.get?e.get.call(t):e.value}var _count=new WeakMap;class Modal{constructor(){_classPrivateFieldInitSpec(this,_count,{writable:!0,value:0})}show({type:t,title:e="",content:s="",buttons:a=[],centered:o=!1,dismissible:i=!0,backdrop:n=!!i||"static",keyboard:r=i,focus:l=!0,fullscreen:d=!1,size:c=""}){_classPrivateFieldSet(this,_count,1+ +_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count)),c=["sm","lg","xl"].includes(c)?`modal-${c}`:"",d=d?"modal-fullscreen":"",o=o?"modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable":"";const b=Bs5Utils.defaults.styles[t],u=b.btnClose.join(" "),m=b.border,h=document.createElement("div");h.setAttribute("id",`modal-${_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count)}`),h.setAttribute("tabindex","-1"),h.classList.add("modal");let p="",v=[];Array.isArray(a)&&a.length&&(p+=`<div class="modal-footer ${m.join(" ")}">`,a.forEach((t,e)=>{switch(t.type||"button"){case"dismiss":p+=`<button type="button" class="${t.class}" data-bs-dismiss="modal">${t.text}</button>`;break;default:let s=`modal-${_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count)}-button-${e}`;p+=`<button type="button" id="${s}" class="${t.class}">${t.text}</button>`,t.hasOwnProperty("handler")&&"function"==typeof t.handler&&v.push({id:s,handler:t.handler})}}),p+="</div>"),h.innerHTML=` <div class="modal-dialog ${o} ${d} ${c}">\n                                <div class="modal-content border-0">\n                                  ${e.length?`<div class="modal-header border-0 ${b.main.join(" ")}">\n                                    <h5 class="modal-title">${e}</h5>\n                                    ${i?`<button type="button" class="btn-close ${u}" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>`:""}\n                                  </div>`:""}\n                                  ${s.length?`<div class="modal-body">${s}</div>`:""}\n                                  ${p}\n                                </div>\n                              </div>`,document.body.appendChild(h),h.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal",function(t){t.target.remove()}),v.forEach(t=>{document.getElementById(t.id).addEventListener("click",t.handler)});const f={backdrop:n,keyboard:r,focus:l},y=new bootstrap.Modal(h,f);return y.show(),y}}var _count2=new WeakMap;class Snack{constructor(){_classPrivateFieldInitSpec(this,_count2,{writable:!0,value:0})}show(t,e,s=0,a=!0){_classPrivateFieldSet(this,_count2,1+ +_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count2));const o=Bs5Utils.defaults.styles[t],i=o.btnClose.join(" "),n=document.createElement("div");n.classList.add("toast","align-items-center","border-1","border-dark"),o.main.forEach(t=>{n.classList.add(t)}),n.setAttribute("id",`snack-${_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count2)}`),n.setAttribute("role","alert"),n.setAttribute("aria-live","assertive"),n.setAttribute("aria-atomic","true"),n.innerHTML=`<div class="d-flex">\n                        <div class="toast-body">${e}</div>\n                        ${a?`<button type="button" class="btn-close ${i} me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>`:""}\n                      </div>`,Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.stacking||document.querySelectorAll(`#${Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.container} .toast`).forEach(t=>{t.remove()}),document.querySelector(`#${Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.container}`).appendChild(n),n.addEventListener("hidden.bs.toast",function(t){t.target.remove()});const r={autohide:s>0&&"number"==typeof s};s>0&&"number"==typeof s&&(r.delay=s);const l=new bootstrap.Toast(n,r);return l.show(),l}}var _count3=new WeakMap;class Toast{constructor(){_classPrivateFieldInitSpec(this,_count3,{writable:!0,value:0})}show({type:t,icon:e="",title:s,subtitle:a="",content:o="",buttons:i=[],delay:n=0,dismissible:r=!0}){_classPrivateFieldSet(this,_count3,1+ +_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count3));const l=Bs5Utils.defaults.styles[t],d=l.btnClose.join(" "),c=l.border,b=document.createElement("div");b.setAttribute("id",`toast-${_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count3)}`),b.setAttribute("role","alert"),b.setAttribute("aria-live","assertive"),b.setAttribute("aria-atomic","true"),b.classList.add("toast","align-items-center"),c.forEach(t=>{b.classList.add(t)});let u="",m=[];Array.isArray(i)&&i.length&&(u+=`<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2 pt-2 border-top ${c.join(" ")}">`,i.forEach((t,e)=>{switch(t.type||"button"){case"dismiss":u+=`<button type="button" class="${t.class}" data-bs-dismiss="toast">${t.text}</button>&nbsp;`;break;default:let s=`toast-${_classPrivateFieldGet(this,_count3)}-button-${e}`;u+=`<button type="button" id="${s}" class="${t.class}">${t.text}</button>&nbsp;`,t.hasOwnProperty("handler")&&"function"==typeof t.handler&&m.push({id:s,handler:t.handler})}}),u+="</div>"),b.innerHTML=`<div class="toast-header ${l.main.join(" ")}">\n                            ${e}\n                            <strong class="me-auto">${s}</strong>\n                            <small>${a}</small>\n                            ${r?`<button type="button" class="btn-close ${d}" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>`:""}\n                        </div>\n                        <div class="toast-body">\n                            ${o}\n                            ${u}\n                        </div>`,Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.stacking||document.querySelectorAll(`#${Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.container} .toast`).forEach(t=>{t.remove()}),document.querySelector(`#${Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.container}`).appendChild(b),b.addEventListener("hidden.bs.toast",function(t){t.target.remove()}),m.forEach(t=>{document.getElementById(t.id).addEventListener("click",t.handler)});const h={autohide:n>0&&"number"==typeof n};n>0&&"number"==typeof n&&(h.delay=n);const p=new bootstrap.Toast(b,h);return p.show(),p}}var _createToastContainer=new WeakSet;class Bs5Utils{constructor(){_classPrivateMethodInitSpec(this,_createToastContainer),_classPrivateMethodGet(this,_createToastContainer,_createToastContainer2).call(this),this.Toast=new Toast,this.Snack=new Snack,this.Modal=new Modal}static registerStyle(t,e){if("object"!=typeof e&&Array.isArray(e))throw"The styles parameter must be an object when you register component style.";Bs5Utils.defaults.styles[t]=e}}function _createToastContainer2(){let t=document.querySelector(`#${Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.container}`);if(!t){const e={"top-left":"top-0 start-0 ms-1 mt-1","top-center":"top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x mt-1","top-right":"top-0 end-0 me-1 mt-1","middle-left":"top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y ms-1","middle-center":"top-50 start-50 translate-middle p-3","middle-right":"top-50 end-0 translate-middle-y me-1","bottom-left":"bottom-0 start-0 ms-1 mb-1","bottom-center":"bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x mb-1","bottom-right":"bottom-0 end-0 me-1 mb-1"};(t=document.createElement("div")).classList.add("position-relative"),t.setAttribute("aria-live","polite"),t.setAttribute("aria-atomic","true"),t.innerHTML=`<div id="${Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.container}" class="toast-container position-fixed pb-1 ${e[Bs5Utils.defaults.toasts.position]||e["top-right"]}"></div>`,document.body.appendChild(t)}}_defineProperty(Bs5Utils,"defaults",{toasts:{position:"top-right",container:"toast-container",stacking:!0},styles:{secondary:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-secondary"],border:["border-secondary"]},light:{btnClose:[],main:["text-dark","bg-light","border-bottom","border-dark"],border:["border-dark"]},white:{btnClose:[],main:["text-dark","bg-white","border-bottom","border-dark"],border:["border-dark"]},dark:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-dark"],border:["border-dark"]},info:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-info"],border:["border-info"]},primary:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-primary"],border:["border-primary"]},success:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-success"],border:["border-success"]},warning:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-warning"],border:["border-warning"]},danger:{btnClose:["btn-close-white"],main:["text-white","bg-danger"],border:["border-danger"]}}});

const bs5Utils = new Bs5Utils();

bs5Utils.Snack.show('secondary', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('light', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('white', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('dark', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('info', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('primary', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('success', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('warning', 'Hello World!', 0, true);
bs5Utils.Snack.show('danger', 'Hello World!', 0, true);

bs5Utils.Toast.show({
    type: 'primary',
    icon: `<i class="far fa-check-circle fa-lg me-2"></i>`,
    title: 'Notification!',
    subtitle: '23 secs ago',
    content: 'Hello World!',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Click Me!',
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
            handler: () => {
                alert(`Button #1 has been clicked!`);
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Click Me Too!',
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
            handler: () => {
                alert(`You clicked me too!`);
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'dismiss',
            text: 'Hide',
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary'
        }
    ],
    delay: 0,
    dismissible: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hqy0czg/

Comment: this is very helpful. I hope in the future you can shrink the size :D. Thank you man..

Answer (score 3):

How onload display toast in  bootstrap 5

**1. add toast snippet**

```
<!--Toast-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="toast" role="alert" data-animation="true" data-autohide="false" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                <div class="toast-header">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/30/30" class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
                <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
                <small>11 mins ago</small>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close ml-2 mb-1 close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body">
                Hello Sarthak
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Toast End-->
```

**2.add javascript**

```
window.onload = (event)=> {
 let myAlert = document.querySelector('.toast');
 let bsAlert = new  bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);
 bsAlert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late in the game, but.. when i was searching to control the "options" i also wanted a way to make the inner data more dynamic and click depended.. so, here is my 2 cents including a way to control the title, the message and even the wrapping class...

Example toast:

```
!--===STR================ TOAST ======================-->
<div class="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
    <div id="liveToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
            <strong class="toast-title me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--===END================ TOAST ======================-->
```

An example on how to launch the toast based a user input,
in this case, a click. i am using an imaginary button with the
id of #tester... :

```
$('#tester').click(function(){
    
    // get the toast container
    var toaster = document.getElementById('liveToast');       

        toaster.classList.remove('success', 'error');
        toaster.classList.add('success');                                       // could be dynamic value class (for css)
        toaster.querySelector('.toast-title').innerHTML = 'toast title';        // could be dynamic value title
        toaster.querySelector('.toast-body').innerHTML = 'some test message';   // could be dynamic value message


    var visibleToast = new bootstrap.Toast(toaster, {'autohide': true, 'delay': 5000});
        visibleToast.show();

});
```

Since this is what I was searching for, I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I made a JavaScript library specially for  that.

Check it out
https://github.com/nawafscript/toaststrap

To use it, simplly download the package and unzip it into your `assets` folder.

Then after include the css and js files to your page, you can use it like this:

```
var toast = Toaststrap.initialize(options);
toast.show();
```

To learn more about options please read the documentation , or try Toaststrap's Initializer

https://nawafscript.github.io/toaststrap/Initializer/index.html