# bootstrap 5 toast show particular toast from list

Tags: css, toast, bootstrap-5

I have been using toast from bootstrap, It works perfectly fine when you are using only one toast to show. But whnever I want to show particular toast from many predifed toasts list such as error toast, then all the other toast also gets displayed. I want to show only one Toast at given time such as success or error or warning etc.
I have tried following but did not worked as expected.

```
$('.toast-error').show();// displays all toast which are defined, but not particular
$('.toast-error').toast('show');// displays all toast which are defined.
```

Following is the html where I added pre-defied all toasts

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative;z-index: 999999">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" class=" p-1" id="toast-content">
    
    <div class="toast bg-success toast-success text-white mt-2" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"  data-bs-animation="true">
      <div class="toast-body">
        Welcome To Project.
        <button type="button" class="pull-right btn-close btn-close-white ms-auto me-2" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toast toast-error bg-danger text-white mt-2" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"  data-bs-animation="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="toast-body">
        Error Occured. Please Refresh Window.
        <button type="button" class="pull-right btn-close btn-close-white ms-auto me-2" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<button class="w-100 btn btn-lg submit" type="button" onclick="validator()">Proceed</button>
<script>
 function validator(){
    $('.toast-error').show();
 }
</script>
```

Is there anywhere I am going wrong.

Comment: You're using class selectors without further specifications, which will trigger all elements with said class. You need to narrow down your JS logic. You have multiple options for this, id's, custom attributes, block selections with find() or "this" etc. etc.

Comment: thanks for help I will try, If possible I'l update

Comment: hey @Martin I got it working using id and attribute. so should i delete this question?

Comment: why is this tagged [bootstrap-5] but the question says [bootstrap-4]?

Comment: @user10384418

I could put the comment as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following it might help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validator(){
 
   var inputEmail    = $('#inputEmail').val();
   var inputPassword = $('#inputPassword').val();

    if(inputEmail.trim()==''){
     $('#toast-error').show();
     $('#toast-error').toggleClass('show');
     $('#inputEmail').focus();
     return false;
  }
  if(inputPassword.trim()==''){
     $('#toast-error').show();
     $('#toast-error').toggleClass('show');
     $('#inputPassword').focus();
     return false;
  }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Comment that lead to solution:***

> You're using class selectors without further specifications, which
> will trigger all elements with said class. You need to narrow down
> your JS logic. You have multiple options for this, id's, custom
> attributes, block selections with find() or "this" etc. etc.

The problem was later resolved by using `IDs` as selectors, as opposed to `class`.

Refer to comments in the question respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is three Years old now and there is BS4 used in the Question, somebody will stumble here as I did:

When you have a Toast List (init explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516035/22715046)), you can still init the single Toasts and use them seperatly.

```
let toast = new bootstrap.Toast(document.getElementById('toastID'))
toast.show();
```

Bootstrap Docs reference to [getOrCreateInstance](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/toasts/#live-example) function, which seems to not work in this context.

This mostly comes way too late, but maybe someone gets a little help out of this.